# Broadcast receiver for GPS state?

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to be notified when the GPS is switched on/off?

I noticed that when the device is switched off an then on again, getLastKnownLocation(provider) is null. So I want to save the location when the GPS is switched off to a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the LocationManager's [PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) Intent. This will be broadcast when the GPS provider (and other providers) is enabled / disabled.