# Notify when GPS activated

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcast reciever for GPS state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446428/broadcast-reciever-for-gps-state)

Is there a listener that can notify me when GPS is activated?
(When user enabled "GPS" button from the notification bar)
I tried using `addGpsStatusListener` but it is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Is this system-wide or only whilst your activity is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok dude, sorry my bad, now I know what you mean, your question is answered here :) 
[Detecting GPS on/off switch in Android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368286/detecting-gps-on-off-switch-in-android-phones)
The only problem is that it only works on API Level 9 and above. I hope this answer your question.

Stay cool, Stay awesome.

Good Luck

Comment: Dude I googled it.. and dude I saw this answer and it is not solving my problem. I know how check if the GPS is on/off. I want to get notified when there is a change.

Comment: sorry dude my bad, I have edited my answer, I hope that help you..Let me know if it answered your question. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks man, It is working good. I guess my question is dup after all, And I need to try google better next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `LocationListener` interface and use the `onProviderEnabled` method.

Comment: I want to get notified when there is a change, not to check by myselef.

Comment: So that is exactly what you need. You don't have to check anything. All you have to do is to implement LocationListener. When the GPS (or another geolocation provider) will be turned on, the method onProviderEnabled will be raised.

Comment: If the GPS_PROVIDER is set in the LocationListener you are true, and onProviderDisabled and onProviderEnabled will work. But if NETWORK_PROVIDER is set it will not work. I have already tried it.

Comment: Well, you can simply create another instance of LocationManager, linked to GPS provider.

Comment: I can but just one provider can be attached to requestLocationUpdates. So I can't see how it will work, but thanks.

Comment: By the way, you didn't mention why addGpsStatusListener() is not the option for you?

Comment: Because it notifies when starts , stops , and searching not when GPS activated from settings or notification bar.